# Simple Injector LoggerFactory in IHostBuilder.ConfigureServices bootstrap

Tags: .net-core, simple-injector

I am using Simple Injector with the generic hosts nuget package, all is well except I have hit a snag with order of registration.

I have a builder class that returns two interfaces, `IMessagePublisher` and `IMessageSubscriber`, this builder class also requires a `ILoggerFactory`.

I am not able to use the `ILoggerFactory` as it is not yet configured, and cannot call `container.GetInstance<ILoggerFactory>` since the container is still being bootstrapped with registrations when the code is called.

My main host is here:

```cs
var host = CreateHostBuilder(args)
   .UseSerilog((hostContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
   {
      var setting = hostContext.Configuration
        .GetSection(Settings.Name).GetAndAssert<Settings>();

      if (setting.IsDebug == true)
          loggerConfiguration.MinimumLevel.Debug();
      else
          loggerConfiguration.MinimumLevel.Information();

      loggerConfiguration
          .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
          .Enrich.FromLogContext()
          .WriteTo.Console()
          .WriteTo.File("logging.log");
  })
  .Build()
  .UseSimpleInjector(container);
```

And my CreateHostBuilder is below (where my issue is in the `builder.Create` method):

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    return Host
        .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, builder) =>
        {
            if (hostContext.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                builder.AddUserSecrets<Program>();
            }
        })
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddSimpleInjector(container, options =>
            {
                options.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                options.AddLogging();

                var mqttSettings = hostContext                                   
                    .Configuration
                    .GetSection(MqttSettings.Name)
                    .GetAndAssert<MqttSettings>();

                var builder = new MqttMessageBusBuilder(mqttSettings);

                builder.Create(
                    new[] { new MessagePackSerializer() },
                    new IdentifyUsingTransportHeaders(),
                    /* below is not allowed */
                    container.GetInstance<ILoggerFactory>,
                    // i also dont know where to get IloggerFactory if not yet configured
                    out var messagePublisher,
                    out var messageSubscriber,
                    mqttSettings.isDebug);

                container.RegisterInstance(messagePublisher);
                container.RegisterInstance(messageSubscriber);
            });
        });
}
```

I am not able to use a Singleton and defer the instantiation until needed, since I need the builder to return the `IMessagePublisher` and `IMessageSubscriber` instances.

I would otherwise have used the below where `container.GetInstance<ILoggerFactory>()` is valid:

```cs
// register factory to create PolygonWebsocket
container.RegisterSingleton( () => {
    var settings = container.GetInstance<Settings>();
    var secrets = container.GetInstance<Secrets>();

    return new PolygonWebsocket(
            secrets.PolygonIoApiKey,
            settings.PolygonWebSocketUrl,
            settings.PolygonReconnectTimeout,
            container.GetInstance<ILoggerFactory>()
    });
```

How can I get the ILoggerFactory injected into my `MqttMessageBusBuilder.Create` method during `CreateHostBuilder` bootstrap?

Comment: https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/servicecollectionintegration.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is not related to Simple Injector, because that `ILoggerFactory` comes from the `IServiceCollection` and its final `IServiceProvider` and this is a chicken-and-the-egg dilemma. Your want to supply `ILoggerFactory` to `MqttMessageBusBuilder.Create` during `ConfigureServices` while the `ILoggerFactory` can only be resolved from `IServiceProvider` when it comes available, which is at a later stage.

To my knowledge, you can do three things:

1. Pull in the `ILoggerFactory` from the `IServiceCollection`, since that registration at that point already exists in the `IServiceCollection`.
2. Postpone the registration of your message interfaces untal *after* `ConfigureServices` (i.e. inside `Configure`)
3. Make the registrations now, but use lazy initialization so that is built when the message interfaces are resolved.

Example for 1:

```cs
.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
{
    var factory = (ILoggerFactory)services
        .Last(s => s.ServiceType == typeof(ILoggerFactory))
        .ImplementationInstance;

    services.AddSimpleInjector(container, options =>
    {
        ...

        var builder = new MqttMessageBusBuilder(mqttSettings);

        builder.Create(
            new[] { new MessagePackSerializer() },
            new IdentifyUsingTransportHeaders(),
            factory,
            out var messagePublisher,
            out var messageSubscriber,
            mqttSettings.isDebug);

        container.RegisterInstance(messagePublisher);
        container.RegisterInstance(messageSubscriber);
    });
});
```

Example for 2:

```cs
var host = 
    CreateHostBuilder(args)
    .UseSerilog((hostContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
    {
        ...
    })
    .Build()
    .UseSimpleInjector(container);

var factory = host.Services.GetRequiredInstance<ILoggerFactory>();

var mqttSettings = hostContext                                   
    .Configuration
    .GetSection(MqttSettings.Name)
    .GetAndAssert<MqttSettings>();

var builder = new MqttMessageBusBuilder(mqttSettings);

builder.Create(
    new[] { new MessagePackSerializer() },
    new IdentifyUsingTransportHeaders(),
    factory,
    out var messagePublisher,
    out var messageSubscriber,
    mqttSettings.isDebug);

container.RegisterInstance(messagePublisher);
container.RegisterInstance(messageSubscriber);

return host;
```

Example for 3:

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    return Host
        .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, builder) =>
        {
            if (hostContext.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                builder.AddUserSecrets<Program>();
            }
        })
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddSimpleInjector(container, options =>
            {
                ...

                var lazy = new Lazy<(
                    IMessagePublisher Publisher,
                    IMessageSubcriber Subscriber)>(() =>
                {
                    var builder = new MqttMessageBusBuilder(mqttSettings);
                
                    builder.Create(
                        new[] { new MessagePackSerializer() },
                        new IdentifyUsingTransportHeaders(),
                        container.GetInstance<ILoggerFactory>(),
                        out var messagePublisher,
                        out var messageSubscriber,
                        mqttSettings.isDebug);
                
                    return (messagePublisher, messageSubscriber);
                });

                container.RegisterSingleton(() => lazy.Value.Publisher);
                container.RegisterInstance(() => lazy.Value.Subscriber);
            });
        });
}
```